# Context Menu for new appointment in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to add a new button to the ribbon when creating or updating an appointment in Outlook 365.

I can't find the right ContextMenu for this (in the ribbon xml file).

Where can I find the context menu for this or is there a resource on the web for easily finding the Context Menu ?

Picture here to show where I want the button (the position is not mandatory).

[image: Position in ribbon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to find the good ContextMenu is to create a Ribbon with the Ribbon composer and not the XML one.

Then, on the properties of the ribbon, you can find "Ribbon type" which will list all type possible.

Comment: What do you mean Ribbon Composer. Is it on the visual Studio